# Join on two related tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables: One for Invoices and other for their payments:

tbl_Invoice

[image: Invoice]

tbl_payment

[image: Payment]

The desire output is as below:

```
PSUM        IPRICE
----------- ------------
312.00      1100.00
```

Where:

`PSUM` is Sum of Payments.

`IPRICE` is Sum of Total_price of that client.

Query I tried is:

```
select 
IsNull(sum(p.amt), 0) PSUM,
IsNull(sum(i.total_price), 0) IPRICE
from tbl_invoice i
left join tbl_payment p
on i.invoice_id = p.invoice_id
    and i.client_id = p.client_id
where i.client_id = 5
group by i.invoice_id
order by i.invoice_id
```

But it gives wrong output:

```
PSUM        IPRICE
----------- ------------
312.00      400.00
0.00        1000.00
```

Comment: Do you want the result to be grouped by invoice_id? or just one record per client (irrespective of how many invoices that client has)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want this. This gives the total sum of the `amt` and the `total_price` with no grouping.  Your version groups by the `invoice_id` which is the difference:

```
select 
  IsNull(sum(p.amt), 0) PSUM,
  IsNull(sum(distinct i.total_price), 0) IPRICE
from tbl_invoice i
left join tbl_payment p
  on i.invoice_id = p.invoice_id
  and i.client_id = p.client_id
where i.client_id = 5
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4bb94/10)

Another way you could write this is using subqueries:

```
select 
  IsNull(sum(p.amt), 0) PSUM,
  IsNull(sum(i.total_price), 0) IPRICE
from
(
  select sum(total_price) total_price, invoice_id, client_id
  from tbl_invoice
  group by invoice_id, client_id
) i
left join
(
  select sum(amt) amt, invoice_id, client_id 
  from tbl_payment
  group by invoice_id, client_id
) p
  on i.invoice_id = p.invoice_id
  and i.client_id = p.client_id
where i.client_id = 5
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4bb94/15)

Both produce the same result:

```
| PSUM | IPRICE |
-----------------
|  312 |   1100 |
```

Comment: Which one is more convenient.??

Comment: @VishalSuthar They both work the same, it really depends on your preference.